# Detect when a validation error appears

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my ASP.NET MVC4 application I'm trying to add images rather than validationmessages (the images have tooltips which contain the error messages).

My only problem is being able to display the images when a validation error message appears (class: field-validation-error).

How can I display the image only when the inner html of the image contains the class field-validation-error?

Or is it somehow possible to intercept the event that occurs when ValidationMessageFor changes the error from valid to error and vice versa?

Comment: are you asking if this is possible using JavaScript?

Comment: @hjavaher
Well I was more thinking in regards to the asp.net MVC framework. Like if there's any way to access and alter the actual validationmessagefor.

Comment: did you tryed add background-image to field-validation-error class ?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I display the image only when the inner html of the image contains the class field-validation-error?

In fact, there is no way to detect class changes dynamically. However there is some work arounds.

I think the best way for you to achieve this, is using the `change` event in jquery. As you know, valideation is only for foorm inputs. So, if you use unobtrusive validation, you can add the following event to all input elements and hatch for changes of their values:

```
$("input").change(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("field-validation-error")) {
        // code to show the relevant image...
    }
});
```